# how can you make inner join with variable

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I would like to make a database query more variable.
The standard method I found on the internet is:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
  ON t1.primary_key = t2.foreign_key
```

But I want the primary key and the foreign key to be used automatically by sql.

I work with PHP and don`t want to do every inner join by hand.

The perfect solution would be if I only needed the table 1 and the table 2.
Without knowing what the primary_key or the foreign key name is.

Comment: _I work with PHP and don`t want to do every inner join by hand..._ Doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Regrettably sql does not have physic powers - astonishing in this day and age...

Comment: You can create views to that has all these queries "saved", but you will at some point have to explicitly describe the JOINs. The computer cannot know what you want it to do unless you tell it to.

Comment: Have you thought about using a ORM like Doctrine?

Comment: There is a way to do that. To me it makes sense to mention PHP here btw.. You can find the primary key of your table like this: `SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'`. Then assemble your join statement in PHP knowing about the primary key.

Comment: How do I find the foreign key?